# Use windows dll libraries in go, compiled for linux and mac os x

Tags: linux, windows, macos, dll, go

I just wonder is there a chance to use proprietary windows dlls in my go project, compiling for mac osx and linux?

Comment: No, you can't do this

Comment: Linux and Mac OS X don't use DLLs. They use shared objects according to the ELF standard. If you manage to compile these proprietary DLLs for Linux / Mac OS X, you will get this kind of shared object. It's no problem to use these in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use windows dlls on Linux / OSX.

However if you really really have to do that, you could always ship your software with a pre-compiled wine like TeamViewer does and few "almost-native" games on Steam.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Go! to much, but assuming these are the same kinds you would use in c++, then no, you cannot do this natively. You would need to use something such as wine (I am not sure if that builds on mac osx though)

Comment: Same opinion. But if you may include repo, go will compile local every lib (but I think OP have a reason for „proprietary”...). What you get from compiling Go! is a C-like program/module, so it must be compiled on each platform with right tools

Comment: well of course if you include the source you can compile it. OP said that hes using proprietary windows dlls so he cant recompile them